# Fixing the seed in QuantLib UniformRandomGenerator()

Tags: python, random, quantlib

I am simulating paths of the Hull-White One Factor process using the following code and I am wondering how I can fix the seed of the UniformRandomGenerator(). I have tried writing UniformRandomGenerator(seed=0), but it keeps returning variable paths.

```
import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sigma = 0.1
a = 0.1
timestep = 3
length = 1 # in years
forward_rate = 0.05
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
todays_date = ql.Date(15, 1, 2015)

ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todays_date

spot_curve = ql.FlatForward(todays_date, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(forward_rate)), day_count)
spot_curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(spot_curve)

hw_process = ql.HullWhiteProcess(spot_curve_handle, a, sigma)
rng = ql.GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator(ql.UniformRandomSequenceGenerator(timestep, ql.UniformRandomGenerator(seed=0)))
seq = ql.GaussianPathGenerator(hw_process, length, timestep, rng, False)

def generate_paths(num_paths, timestep):
    arr = np.zeros((num_paths, timestep+1))
    for i in range(num_paths):
        sample_path = seq.next()
        path = sample_path.value()
        time = [path.time(j) for j in range(len(path))]
        value = [path[j] for j in range(len(path))]
        arr[i, :] = np.array(value)
    return np.array(time), arr

num_paths = 1
time, path = generate_paths(num_paths, timestep)
for i in range(path.shape[1]):
    print(path[0][i])
```

Comment: You need to supply some debugging details. What, specifically, is going wrong? What were you expecting that you're not getting? Why do you think it's because of seeding? Do you understand what seeding a generator means?

Comment: Hi @pjs, I want the code to return the same set of paths every time I run the code.

Comment: Have you tried giving it a non-zero seed? Documentation says zero is the default, but doesn't say what it does. Usually for PRNGs that means it's using system time, /dev/random, or a combination of both. If you give it a non-zero fixed value, it should yield reproducible results.

Comment: Yuk, that's a terrible magic value. @pjs I think this one might actually require an answer. It's not like a seed of zero *should* be any kind of special, I have the feeling principle of least surprise got raped on this one.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm not sure PLS applies when you have a port of a C++ library into python. I'm also old enough that my early experiences were with Prime Modulus Multiplicative Linear Congruential Generators, a.k.a. [Lehmer Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator), where a seed value of zero was a sin that condemned you for all eternity. The use of zero as a seed has always seemed bizarre to me.